# Sort categories by a regular expression, letters then characters/numbers

Tags: magento-enterprise, category, mysql, sorting

Is there a way to sort a collection by a regular expression? as far as I can tell, there is only setOrder() on a collection, where you put the column, and then asc or desc. I want to be able to sort such that if my data is:

- foo
- bar
- 7
- baz
- 19

the results would be 
**bar, baz, foo, 19, 7**

instead of **19, 7, bar, baz, foo**.

Comment: can you please update your regular expression?

Comment: i was thinking something like order by name regexp [a-zA-Z] asc

Comment: let me check and let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each (db) collection has a `Zend_Db_Select` member associated to it. the order in collection is given by the `order` set on the select object.
From what I know (I may be wrong) you cannot order by a regex in mysql because that evaluates to 0 or 1.

If you still want to try you can play arround with the select you get from

```
$collection->getSelect();
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up sorting the categories into buckets, one for each letter and than an additional bucket for all other characters, because that is what I needed as requirements changed. I then checked to see if the first bucket was a letter, and if it was not, then I shifted it to the end of the array.